# Is adding a Download Limit to the Soundcloud Widget possible?

Tags: soundcloud

Hi Soundcloud developers,

is there any way for you to add a download limit to the standard soundcloud widget?

`<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F110900242%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-G1Cy7&amp;color=00adef&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true"></iframe>`

I imagine adding download_limit=100 to the widget code or something like that... Would be very helpful!

Comment: I would ask at the sound cloud forums for an answer to this...http://help.soundcloud.com/

Comment: The only way to get in contact with the development team seams to be this site. (see: http://developers.soundcloud.com/support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have some experience with javascript, you can check for `download_count` of the track with soundcloud api before you show the widget.
if `download_count <= 100` simple put `&download=true` else `&download=false`

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with Javascript - I'm just a marketing guy and not a developer. So my question might sound stupid: Would I have to add the Javascript to the website or code my own widget that includes the necessary script?

Comment: i don't think that soundcloud has integrated what you're looking in their widget. so, yes, you will need to add few lines of code in your page.